# FTP apache commons progress bar in java

Tags: java, ftp, progress-bar, apache-commons-net

I'm working on a little program, which can upload a file to my FTP Server and do some other stuff with it.
Now... It all works, i'm using the `org.apache.commons.net.ftp FTPClient` class for uploading.

```
ftp = new FTPClient();
ftp.connect(hostname);
ftp.login(username, password);

ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/shares/public");
int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();

if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
    addLog("Uploading...");
} else {
    addLog("Failed connection to the server!");
}

File f1 = new File(location);
in = new FileInputStream(

ftp.storeFile(jTextField1.getText(), in);

addLog("Done");

ftp.logout();
ftp.disconnect();
```

The file which should uploaded, is named in hTextField1.
Now... How do i add a progress bar? I mean, there is no stream in ftp.storeFile... How do i handle this?

Thanks for any help! :)

Greetings

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do it using the [CopyStreamListener](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/io/CopyStreamListener.html), that according to Apache commons docs is `the listener to be used when performing store/retrieve operations.`

```
CopyStreamAdapter streamListener = new CopyStreamAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void bytesTransferred(long totalBytesTransferred, int bytesTransferred, long streamSize) {
       //this method will be called everytime some bytes are transferred

       int percent = (int)(totalBytesTransferred*100/yourFile.length());
       // update your progress bar with this percentage
    }

 });
ftp.setCopyStreamListener(streamListener);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, that works!
But now i got another problem... If i press on the button which uploads the file, the program freezes, and if the upload is done the full progressbar is full...

Comment: That's because you do the upload in the GUI thread, so the GUI freezes, and waits for your upload to be done, a way to avoid that is using [Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), there is an example: [Thread Example](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-threads-tutorial)

Comment: After hours of searching, finally found a solution that worked for me. +1! Thanks @BackSlash!